# Javascript - 'assert' not working on Safari, but works fine on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, json, safari

I have a file named `data.json` whose data I want to import into and be parsed by `main.js`, like so:

`import data from './data.json' assert { type: 'json' };`

To test it, I'm running a local server and it all works fine when on Chrome, but with Safari it gives this error: [image: SafariError]

I'm kinda new to the whole webdev thing, so I'm A) not sure I understand what this error is saying and B) can't seem to find many others with a similar problem? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 2):

The situation is confusing. Here is what I understood so far:

- Initially, Safari supported Import Assertions from Safari 15
- After that, the [Import Assertions proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes) got downgraded from stage 3 to stage 2. In reaction, Webkit maintainers [disabled the support of Import Assertions](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/128#issuecomment-1418738648). Since then, static import such as `import data from "./test.json" assert { type: "json" }` are not working anymore.

However, only static import assertions are impacted. The dynamic import syntax remains functional (tested with Safari 16.5.2) `const { default: data } = await import("./test.json", { assert: { type: "json" } })`

The proposal is now back in stage-3 with a new syntax (the `assert` keyword has been replaced by `with`). I don't know when browsers will be supporting this new syntax.

I will be testing this 2 approaches in the coming days:

- [The es-module-shims polyfill by guybedford](https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims)
- Using dynamic imports instead of static imports

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Safari bag or something like that. You can use this:

```
window.onload = async function () {
    const response = await fetch("./data.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that Safari can't do such asserted import.
If we check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_import_import_assertions_type_json) we will find that Safari **up to 14.1 version** doesn't support json imports.

Comment: I am having this error with Safari 16.5.2